# how to export users from samba DC and import into MS Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba4

I have Linux with running Samba DC. i want to export users and import into MS Active Directory and inverse.how do that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, remember that you can configure Windows Professional station to connect to Samba DC as administration station. There is special package, something like

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308196/how-to-install-the-active-directory-administrative-tools-to-windows-20

Then it is simple, just use one of technet help like
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bettertogether/2011/01/09/import-bulk-users-to-active-directory/

Comment: thanks.but not any way in linux to export users?

Comment: You can use samba-tool as a tool to list users, but I don't think that will work for importing to MS AD.